# useEffect code not firing dispatch even though it works without?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've been troubleshooting and I narrowed it down to the useEffect.

This code as-is won't fire the dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id)) as shown in the redux dev tools.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CheckoutSteps from '../components/CheckoutSteps'
import { getOrderByIdAction } from '../state/actions/orderActions'
import Message from '../components/Message'

const OrderConfirmationScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    // From Order Confirmation State 
    const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderConfirmation.orderDetails)
    const shippingAddress = orderDetails.shippingAddress
    const paymentMethod = orderDetails.paymentMethod
    const orderItems = orderDetails.orderItems

    // Calculator Order Summary
    const itemPrice = orderItems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc + (cur.price * cur.qty)
    }, 0)
    const taxPrice = Number((itemPrice * .1).toFixed(2))
    const totalPrice = taxPrice + itemPrice

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id))
        }
    },[])

    return (
        <div className="main-container lg:p-16">
        <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 />
            <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto p-8 my-8 w-full">
                <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
                    <div className="place-order-container bg-gray-50 rounded-md shadow-2xl m-2 p-6 lg:p-12 w-full">
                        <h1 className="text-center font-semibold text-xl mt-4 mb-6">Place Order</h1>
                        {/* { error && <Message message={ "Hello" }/>} */}
                        <div className="order-header-group grid grid-cols-2 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl pt-4 pb-8 px-2">
                            <div className="order-shipping-section my-2 mx-4 lg:p-2">
                                <h4 className="font-medium my-4">Shipping Address: </h4>
                                <div className="address-group">
                                    <h6 className="text-sm">{shippingAddress.address}</h6>
                                    <h6 className="text-sm">{shippingAddress.city}, {shippingAddress.zipcode}</h6>
                                    <h6 className="text-sm">{shippingAddress.phone}</h6>
                                    { shippingAddress && 
                                    <Link to={'/shipping'} className="underline my-2 block">Edit</Link> }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="order-payment-section my-2 lg:p-2">
                                <h4 className="font-medium my-4">Payment Method: </h4>
                                { paymentMethod === 'Paypal' && <i className="fab fa-paypal fa-lg mr-2" style={{color: "#253B80"}}></i>}
                                <span className="text-sm">{paymentMethod}</span> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="order-items-group my-3 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-2xl p-2 lg:p-4">
                            <div className="order-items-group rounded-md p-6">
                                { orderItems.map((item, index) => 
                                    <div key={item.productId} className="grid grid-cols-8 gap-2 items-center my-4">
                                        <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} className="col-span-2 w-40 p-4" />    
                                        <h6 className="col-span-3 text-sm">{item.name}</h6>
                                        <h6 className="col-span-1 text-sm text-center">{item.qty}</h6> 
                                        <h6 className="col-span-1 text-sm text-center">x</h6>
                                        <h6 className="col-span-1 text-sm text-center">{item.price}</h6> 
                                        <hr className="my-4 col-span-8"/> 
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="order-total-section bg-gray-50 rounded-md shadow-2xl m-2 p-6 lg:pb-8 w-full lg:w-2/5 h-1/2">
                        <h4 className="font-semibold text-xl text-center my-8">Order Summary</h4>
                        <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-2xl p-4">
                            <div className="items-total grid grid-cols-3 p-1">
                                <span className="col-span-2 my-2 block text-sm">Items: </span>
                                <span className="col-span-1 my-2 block text-sm">${itemPrice} </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="shipping-total grid grid-cols-3 p-1">
                                <span className="col-span-2 my-2 block text-sm">Shipping: </span>
                                <span className="col-span-1 my-2 block text-sm">FREE </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="tax-total grid grid-cols-3 p-1">
                                <span className="col-span-2 my-2 block text-sm">Tax: </span>
                                <span className="col-span-1 my-2 block text-sm">${taxPrice} </span>
                            </div>
                            <hr className="my-2" />
                            <div className="total-total grid grid-cols-3 p-1">
                                <span className="col-span-2 my-2 block text-sm font-semibold">Total: </span>
                                <span className="col-span-1 my-2 block text-sm font-semibold">${totalPrice} </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    );
};

export default OrderConfirmationScreen;
```

If I just run dispatch without useEffect, it will fire off with a success and I get all the order info on my reducer. So I know it has something to do with the useEffect.

Unfortunately, then I get an error that says orderDetails is undefined because I need useEffect to run it before the component renders?

Not sure what I did wrong

EDIT:

```
instructor's orderScreen.js

const OrderScreen = ({ match, history }) => {
  const orderId = match.params.id

  const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails)
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails

  const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay)
  const { loading: loadingPay, success: successPay } = orderPay

  const orderDeliver = useSelector((state) => state.orderDeliver)
  const { loading: loadingDeliver, success: successDeliver } = orderDeliver

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  if (!loading) {
    //   Calculate prices
    const addDecimals = (num) => {
      return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
    }

    order.itemsPrice = addDecimals(
      order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history.push('/login')
    }

    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
      const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal')
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.type = 'text/javascript'
      script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`
      script.async = true
      script.onload = () => {
        setSdkReady(true)
      }
      document.body.appendChild(script)
    }

    if (!order || successPay || successDeliver || order._id !== orderId) {
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_RESET })
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_RESET })
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
    } else if (!order.isPaid) {
      if (!window.paypal) {
        addPayPalScript()
      } else {
        setSdkReady(true)
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, orderId, successPay, successDeliver, order])

  const successPaymentHandler = (paymentResult) => {
    console.log(paymentResult)
    dispatch(payOrder(orderId, paymentResult))
  }

  const deliverHandler = () => {
    dispatch(deliverOrder(order))
  }

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
  ) : ( jsx
```

```
edited code
OrderConfirmation.js

const OrderConfirmationScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    // From Order Confirmation State 
    const orderConfirmation = useSelector((state) => state.orderConfirmation)
    const { loading, error, orderDetails } = orderConfirmation
   
    useEffect(() => {
        if(id) {
        console.log(id);
        dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id))}
    },[id])

    const shippingAddress = orderDetails.shippingAddress
    const paymentMethod = orderDetails.paymentMethod
    const orderItems = orderDetails.orderItems

    // Calculator Order Summary
    const itemPrice = orderItems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc + (cur.price * cur.qty)
    }, 0)
    const taxPrice = Number((itemPrice * .1).toFixed(2))
    const totalPrice = taxPrice + itemPrice

    return  loading? (<h3>loading..</h3>) :
        ( jsx
```

Comment: `id` is probably `undefined`, log it inside the effect before the condition. If it is, include your routes

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id))
        }
    },[id])

Comment: Your `id` is propobly empty at the start. hence you specified that `useEffect` has a dependency of an empty array `[]` it will only fire once at the start of a component render. If you fill up `id` later - it wont re-fire `useEffect`. add `id` as a dependency

Comment: Also, if you fetch the order details through an http request, you won't be able to destructure the data before it completes and the state of the store is updated

Comment: @AsafAviv logging ID shows it's there. Dispatch will work (kindof) outside of the useEffect and I'll get the info back from the backend properly

Comment: So I double checked and added Id as a dependency and the problem is still the same. Dispatch isn't firing at all.

Comment: So yeah, you need to wait for the http request to complete before you destructure any variables inside `orderDetails`

Comment: If I type dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id) without useEffect, redux dev tools shows that it is firing with success. unfortunately the problem is orderDetails is undefined in that case

Comment: @AsafAviv this makes sense when I run dispatch without useEffect. But the problem still remains that the dispatch doesn't fire when in useEffect, with dependencies. Not sure why...

Comment: If my answer still doesn't solve your problem, please add the action and the reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is not in the store when you render the component, you have to wait for the http request to complete.

You can return `null` when `orderDetails` is `undefined`, but consider adding a `loading` and `error` state to give a better user experience and make it easier for you to render a loading component or displaying an error

```js
const OrderConfirmationScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { id } = useParams();
    // From Order Confirmation State
    const orderDetails = useSelector(
        state => state.orderConfirmation.orderDetails,
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id));
        }
    }, [id]);

    // This is the important part.
    // consider replacing this condition with loading and error from your state
    if (!orderDetails) return <h3>Loading ...</h3>;

    const { shippingAddress, paymentMethod, orderItems } = orderDetails;

    // Calculator Order Summary
    const itemPrice = orderItems.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc + cur.price * cur.qty;
    }, 0);
    const taxPrice = Number((itemPrice * 0.1).toFixed(2));
    const totalPrice = taxPrice + itemPrice;

    return jsx...
};
```

Comment: I added action, reducer and store to my post. Still stumped. I have almost identical code in other pages like profile but useEffect not firing actions at all is weird

Comment: ```
const OrderConfirmationScreen = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    // From Order Confirmation State 
    const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderConfirmation.orderDetails)
   
    useEffect(() => {
        if(id) {
        console.log(id);
        dispatch(getOrderByIdAction(id))}
    },[id])

    const shippingAddress = orderDetails.shippingAddress
    const paymentMethod = orderDetails.paymentMethod
    const orderItems = orderDetails.orderItems

    return ( jsx
```
onsole log in useEffect is not running either

Comment: @pancake Copy my code and replace your current implementation, just replace `return jsx...` with what you want to render when the `orderDetails` is there. you need to return `null` or something else before you access properties inside `orderDetails`.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. I copied verbatim and it worked. And now I understand what you meant by returning null. Peering over the code, I didn't have a conditional render for a loader component in my JSX.

Comment: If I can bother you another time.. I uploaded the tutorial instructor's solution and my edited code to see if I can match his. He has the destructured variables all up top and then in the return he has loader? return <Loader/ > : return (jsx).. 

How come his code is correct but when I add a conditional render to mine (below his) I'm still getting the error?

Comment: Actually i understand my mistake. I’m assigning orderDetails.shippingAddress to a variable and this isn’t possible because it’s not loaded.